# Is it posible to use django_select2 widgets with a Wagtail ParentalManyToManyField

Tags: wagtail

I need a complex selection widget because there are a lot of options in a multiple select widget. But I see HeavySelect2MultipleWidget needs views and urls to use it. I think there is not possible it in Wagtail by default.

This is the code:

```
class Resource(Page):
authors  = ParentalManyToManyField('Authors', blank=True)

content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel('authors',  widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
]
```

It would be nice to use

```
 FieldPanel('authors',  widget=HeavySelect2MultipleWidget)
```

but it raises a

> You must ether specify "data_view" or "data_url".

Answer (score 3):

According to the Django-Select2 documentation you have to initiate (call) the widget with the attributes first.

As the error says - `data_url` or `data_view` has not been provided to the widget.

It will be up to you to generate that view or url specific to your use case. You could [override the serve method](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/reference/pages/model_recipes.html#overriding-the-serve-method) of your page model to serve the data and provide the appropriate url pattern or simply create a different view altogether as documented [here (see Heavy Components section)](http://blog.applegrew.com/2012/08/django-select2/).

For example:

```
FieldPanel(
    'authors', 
    widget=HeavySelect2MultipleWidget(
        data_url='url/to/json/resonse'
    )
)
```

HeavySelect2MultipleWidget extends HeavySelect2Widget - see docs for more detail:
http://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django_select2.html#django_select2.forms.HeavySelect2Widget

I have not used this specific widget but have used Django-Select2 in Wagtail in a similar set up and it has worked well.